# Spam mask does not appear when viewing answers from within review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, deleted-answers, spam

I was in Close votes review queue and came across this [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/31442044).

When clicking the answer tab I see:
[image]

However, when I go to the [actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71638602/15497888) I see the spam mask that I would have to click through to the revision history to see the actual text:
[image]

I would think that if the spam mask is going to be shown it should appear everywhere the answer appears.

Comment: This appears to be [status-by-design], and unrelated to the post not being locked https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360775

Comment: Thanks for that @cigien I had looked for bug reports but I didn't come across that answer. Also good to know that it’s not a niche issue just related to only one of the ways the spam mask appears.

Comment: I still think consistency makes more sense on the whole. And I’m not sure that there’s an reason to show it in review if it’s not going to be shown elsewhere. Though I understand if it’s a hassle to implement or there’s a reason why it shouldn’t be masked that I’m unaware of.

Comment: I think this should be a [feature-request] rather than a [bug] if you feel the behavior should be changed. Or even a [discussion] if you're not sure.

Comment: When I wrote this question I believed it to be a \[bug\] for similar reasons as the [initial bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360775/1099857). Even though it is \[status-by-design\] my initial intent was for this to be a bug report. If it's not a bug, I don't have a vested interest in getting it changed (\[feature-request\]). Since it's a cross site duplicate, I think leaving it as a bug report (and potentially tagged \[status-by-design\]) is a reasonable approach. Then it's a viable dupe target for the future in case it comes up again.

Comment: Rude/abusive posts don't become audits, so the concern/justification mentioned in the linked [initial bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360775/1099857) does not apply. For spam posts, if they were indicated as spam in the review queue, the review task would become *too* obvious, even for a robo-reviewer.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree that a known-spam audit should not display the spam mask, but audits already have permission to change various attributes about the post: score, content, deletion state, close state, etc. But, this answer is not an audit, it's not even the post I'm (directly) reviewing, it's an associated answer to a question under review. So my thinking was that it would appear with the spam mask like it does if I were to look at the answers of this question outside of review.